# How can i find a pattern in an array of integers?

Tags: c, arrays, integer, pattern-finding

A week ago I got my homework, where I have to write a function in C.
The function gets a single array of positive integers, and it has to return the next number in the array.
The arrays look something like this: {1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,-1};
-1 means the end of the array.

I know that the number which has to be returned by the function is 1, however, how can I code a pattern finding algorithm? I haven't found any solution on the internet, since every other question about pattern searching is with strings, where the pattern which has to be found is already given.

Comment: Please provide more detail of possible inputs.

Comment: You shouldn't have gotten homework about something which wasn't taught in the class, so please go through your class-notes and see if you can find a hint there.

Comment: The possible inputs are an array of integers, and in general they look something like this: 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,-1; where -1 means the end of the array, as the description of my homework states.

Comment: I have gone trough my notes but i did not find anything.

Answer (score 3):

if the pattern has a length of `1`, you will have `a[k+1] == a[k]` for all possible `k`.

more generally, you will have `a[k+plen] == a[k]` for the correct `plen` (pattern length) and all possible `k`.

so determine `plen` starting with `1`... in your case you get `7` because `a[7]==a[0]`, `a[8]==a[1]`, ... `a[16]==a[9]`, so just return `a[17-7]`.

Comment: alternatively just say the pattern is the whole input and return the 1st element :)

Answer (score 0):

Building on the [answer by pmg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58659156/440558) one simple way to determine `plen` is to use brute force:

Begin by assuming `plen` is equal to `1`, and increase `plen` by `1` until a pattern is found.

You find a pattern by checking if the sequence starting at every `plen` element match the first `plen` elements of the array. So if the current `plen` is `3`, then you check if elements at index `3` to `5` (inclusive) matches the elements at index `0` to `2` (inclusive). If they match you check the next sequence starting at index `6`. And so on.

If the end-of-array marker `-1` is in the sequence you're just searching, then you have `plen`. And if a sequence is not matching then start over with an increased `plen` and try again.